# Leaflet VectorGrid interactivity doesn't work if Leaflet.markercluster is used

Tags: leaflet, javascript

This is a cross-post from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044795/leaflet-vectorgrid-interactivity-doesnt-work-if-leaflet-markercluster-is-used). I am trying to use Leaflet VectorGrid [interactivity](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html#interactivity) option for click and mouse events:

```
const vectorGrid = L.vectorGrid.slicer(geoJsonDocument, {
    rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
    vectorTileLayerStyles: {
      sliced: geoJSONStyle(false)
    },
    maxZoom: 22,
    indexMaxZoom: 5, // max zoom in the initial tile index
    interactive: true
  });

  vectorGrid.on("mouseover", function (e) {
    console.log("mouseover");
  });

  vectorGrid.on("click", function (e) {
    console.log("click");
  });
```

However, interactivity doesn't work if Leaflet.markercluster is used.

I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-darwin-m4pxr?file=/src/index.js).

If you comment `map.addLayer(mcg);`, interactivity works.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/67044795/820534